# Another word for "shot"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I always find myself using phrases such as "fear shot through him" or "adrenaline shot through his veins" or "a shot of adrenaline coursed through him".  What are some other words that I can use to replace shot in these instances?

Fill in the blank: Relief _ through his veins.

Comment: Coursed.  Of course.

Comment: That would work and it occurred to me, but "shot" has more of an immediate sort of tension to it.  "Fear shot through his veins" feels more intense than "fear coursed through his veins".  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I always used the noun **rush** after *adrenaline* as it means a "rapid, impetuous, or violent onward movement".

[*Adrenaline rush*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adrenaline-rush):

> a sudden burst of energy from an increase in the hormone and
>   neurotransmitter adrenaline, esp. increased heart rate and blood
>   pressure, perspiration, blood sugar, and metabolism

[Dictionary.com]

Your example:

> Adrenaline **rushed** through his veins

Answer (score 0):

Verbs like *surge* and *rush* are appropriate for emotions like fear, or chemicals like adrenaline.

However, you ended your question with this one:

> Fill in the blank: *Relief _______ through his veins*.

For something more associated with relaxation than tension, a different set of verbs may be more appropriate.

I would suggest *seeped*:

> *Relief seeped through his veins*.